# Upgrading Cube Aim 29 2013

Tags: shimano, parts, upgrades, groupsets

I'm thinking about upgrading my bike Cube Aim 29 2013.
Current configuration described [here](http://www.chainreactioncycles.com/ru/en/cube-aim-29-hardtail-bike-2013/rp-prod111924).
The bike is completely ok for short rides, but for longer rides doesn't feel comfortable. So I'm going to change saddle and pedals, but I also want to make it more suitable for off-road rides.

I'm considering Shimano components. Is it reasonable to buy something like [XT M785 10 Speed Double Groupset](http://www.chainreactioncycles.com/ru/en/shimano-xt-m785-10-speed-double-groupset/rp-prod116657)? Or SLX level components would be enough?

Regarding the frame - it is in good condition and Cube uses the same frame for their higher-end hard-tail bikes.

Comment: Given how low end the parts on that bike are, I'd probably sell it and buy something with higher end parts to begin with.

Comment: A little more info on the problem you're trying to solve would help us give advice. Why do you want to upgrade? What do you use it for, such that XYZ *components would be enough?* Will you do your own work? What is the frame quality and condition?

Comment: @andy256, you are right, I updated the question

Comment: Starting spending money in the bike is overkill giving it's low-end components. Besides, none of those components will make it more comfortable or more "suitable" for MTB. If everything is working you're much better saving for a new one while spending as little as possible here. Also if you want to make it more comfortable a saddle will surely help but apart from that there isn't much you can do (and pedals surely won't). You can get new tires if yours are old and used, and you could get a new suspension there but again, I think you're better of saving for a new bike.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Don't buy that XT groupset** for that bike to solve those problems - it wont work.

XT is great, but it won't make your  bike more comfortable, and it wont make it better off-road. Worse, it wont work for that bike since it has V-brakes, and that groupset has disk brakes.  They are not compatible.

To make it better off-road you need (in this order) better forks, disk brakes,  better components (lighter and stronger) and lighter frame.

I agree with what others have said here: sell it, and upgrade the whole bike.  If you really can't do that, only go for SLX.